# calling a jQuery function from another JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to databind a gridview on a button click event. so that i am going to add a jQuery function for databind. but that function should be called inside a JavaScript function.

like this,

```
function btnclick() {
    //code
    //here i want to call the databind function
}
$(function () {
    //code
}
```

this is just my assumption. i don't know how to combine jQuery function and JavaScript function. any suggestion?

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library, so what is the problem ?

Comment: can we use both combined? because  once i have used javascript and jquery in a same page. but both conflicted. if one works then another will not work. so what i want is simply how to call a jquery method from another javscript function. u can add your own example too. i want just the syantax and the logic. thats it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call the function as you call in javascript function. its quiet simple.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        databind();
    });
  });
  function databind(){
   //your code
  }
```

Comment: Why create an anonymous function inside the `.click(...)` call? How about using `$("#btn").click(databind);`?

Answer (score 1):

you can bind the jquery event or use jquery inside a javascript function like this:

```
function btnClick(){
    $("yourelement").bind("eventyouchoose",function(e){
        //task to do in when the event is called
    });
    //perform actions using jquery in the similar way
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it would help but the databind method will be called from some other functions too. its a common function.

Comment: well in that case may be you can create a function like initListeners() which holds the jquery code. And call the initListeners() function from the js methods you want.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is simply a library written in JavaScript, so you can freely call JS/jQuery methods in any scope where they are loaded.

I'm not sure what you meant with your code sample, but a common way to perform an action on click would be with the [jQuery click() method](http://api.jquery.com/click/) like so:

```
function databind() {
    // some kinda magic
}
// pass your previously defined databind function as the callback
$('some-selector').click(databind);
```

You need to specify a selector to target the clickable button.